# How to find the area of any irregular shape?

Tags: area

how to find the area of any irregular shapes without dividing it into smaller regular shapes ?

Example Image:

[image: Irregular Shape]

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method.

Comment: If you could express the boundary as a closed curve, then you could calculate the area.

Comment: Do you know how to take an integral?

Comment: There are machines, I mean real-live analog devices, that perform this task. You trace over the curve, and when you get back to the starting point, the machine indicates the area enclosed.

Comment: @Lubin The name for this device is a [planimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter).

Comment: I don't even know how to define the area of an irregular shape without dividing it into small pieces. What does it mean to say that an irregular shape has an area, if not that you can cut it into small pieces and rearrange them into a square?

Comment: The definition of area (basically outer measure) of a set: You cover the set with rectangles (for these we know the area, base times height) and then take the covering that has the smallest sum of the areas of the rectangles (infimum, actually).

Comment: That is the same as cutting the region into small pieces; in this case narrow strips.

Comment: @MJD Do you mean that all the shapes are discrete ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ask us to avoid breaking the image into smaller shapes, yet your input, a JPEG image, is essentially already just that.  Even the suggestion to use integration relies on breaking the object up into infinitessimal parts.  So I'm not not going to avoid the obvious.

Of course, we need a scale so here's another copy of your image:

[image]

Let's assume that the rectangle bounding this image has area 1.  Then it's just a matter of counting the gray pixels and dividing by the total number of pixels.  Applying a little Mathematica code to your original image, which has different dimensions from mine, we get

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZriDw.jpg"];
data = MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[img]];
N[Count[Flatten[data], 1]/Times @@ Dimensions[data]]

(* Out: 0.466297 *)
```

Comment: There is a similar method which was used historically (I think by some famous physicists): Print the shape, cut it out, weight it and calculate the area from the density of the paper.

Answer (score 4):

Like noted in the comments, if you have a (piece-wise smooth, Jordan curve) parametrization $\gamma = (\gamma_1, \gamma_2) : [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ of the boundary, the area enclosed by $\gamma$ can be calculated by Green's theorem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem

For example using $L=0$ and $M(x,y) = x$ we have the formula

$$A= \int_D 1=  \int_{0}^1 \gamma_1(t) \gamma_2'(t)dt. $$

Comment: Brilliant because it does not partition the surface as a Riemann integral would: +1

Answer (score 2):

Approximate the figure by a polygonal line, draw a rectangular grid $\big($lattice$\big)$ inside the image, and apply [Pick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem).